# TCP Communication between Windows (Client) and Linux

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm working on a robot that is controlled by an xbox controller connected to a windows computer and commands are sent to a pcduino through a tcp connection. I have it working by sending a string of 1's and 0's to tell the pcduino which motors to turn on. I'm trying to optimize it by just sending an int and using bit masks to make the decisions on the pcduino but I can't get the pcduino to receive the int correctly. I tested the windows function sending the command with sokit and its sending the correct values but the pcduino is receiving the same number even when the commands are changing.

This is what its doing:

Windows          -> PCDuino

command = 1      -> sendBuff = 73932

cmdstring = 1    -> n = 1

---

command = 1025   -> sendBuff = 73932

cmdstring = 1025 -> n = 4

---

My windows functions are:

```
bool Client::Send(char * smsg)
{
    int iResult = send(ConnectSocket, smsg, strlen(smsg), 0);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Sending Message has failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        Stop();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
    bool sendCommand()
{
    cmdbuffer << command;
    cmdstring = cmdbuffer.str();

    if (!client->Send((char *)cmdstring.c_str()))
    {
        std::cout << "Disconnected from Server. Press Enter to Exit";
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.get();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

PCDuino Program

```
/******************************************************************************/

/*Connection Globals*/
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
int n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
char sendBuff[1025];
time_t ticks;

/******************************************************************************/


void setup()
{

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    listen(listenfd, 10);

    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

/******************************************************************************/


    digitalWrite(MineMode, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
    recBuff = 0;
    deviceFlag = 0;

    //Read Socket

/******************************************************************************/

    n = read(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
    recBuff = atoi(sendBuff);

/******************************************************************************/
    }
```

---

I have a printf after the read call and that's where I am getting the 73932 number. I think I have everything you guys need but if there's anything else I need to add let me know. I'm stumped...I don't know if its just a casting problem or what.

Comment: Does the server send a null terminator? `atoi()` will rely on their being a null marking the end of the received string. Also you should check for  errors after reading before using the data.

Comment: Reduce your code to the smallest code necessary to reproduce the problem. I.e., no code noise. If we need to see huge tables of `const`, there's almost certainly code noise. That aside, I can't help but notice you are not doing any error checking in your code on the PCDuino side. That makes your question cry.

Comment: You appear to be showing the code that works rather than the code that doesn't work - the one that sends an int.

Chances are, you are running into endianess. Try converting the int you send with `sendValue = htonl(sendValue);` and converting it back in the pcduino program with `recvValue = ntohl(recvValue);`

Comment: I was under the impression that using the .c_str call returned a null terminated string but I'll definitely have to try just adding one before the call.

I'm not error checking because the method I was using before worked with no problems. I was sending a string of 0's and 1's but wanted to decrease the amount of data being sent by just using an int.

@kfsone do you know if using htonl will I be able to cast the result to a char* to send or am I going to have to rewrite my client send function? I'm heading back to the shop soon and will try both the suggestions.

Comment: You are not sending ints, you are sending decimal numbers as ASCII text. I suppose it is a small improvement over sending binary numbers as ASCII text, but I still wouldn't call it much of an "optimization" (you could also send HEX number, they would be both more readable to humans here, and shorter than decimal). But, critical thing to remember: TCP/IP is a byte stream protocol, so you can't receive raw messages with it, you need your own message protocol on top of it (such as 0 byte delimited ASCII strings).

Comment: You do not have a sensible protocol. The sender sends a number in ASCII with no end marker. The receiver has no idea how large the number is, so if it receives "113", that might be the number, or it might be "1134". You are treating TCP as if it was a message protocol, but it's not. You need a message protocol, but have not written one.

Answer (score 0):

> bool Client::Send(char * smsg)

you not change data here, so use `const char *` at least

> send(ConnectSocket, smsg, strlen(smsg), 0)

If you send variable length message via `TCP`, you should tell
somehow another side of connection how many bytes you send,
for example use first 4 bytes as length

> n = read(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));

you not receive any bytes here yet, so `strlen(sendBuff)` is useless and dangerous,
you should make sure that you receive data with ending 0 byte, before
call strlen.

Plus you should never assume that if you send N bytes by one chunk,
you recieve N bytes on another side by one chunk,
so you client should be finite state machine:

1. Wait 4 bytes with length of packet (call `read` in loop until it return 4 bytes to you in sum). Convert 4 bytes to length of message (N).

   ```
   size_t read_bytes = 0;
   while (read_bytes < 4) {
   ssize_t n = read();

   if (n < 0)
     handle_error();
   else if (n == 0)
     handle_n_equal_to_0_case();
   else
    read_bytes += n;
   }
   ```
2. Wait N bytes (call `read` in loop similar to (1)). Not forget to use rest of bytes that you receive on step 1.

Comment: `n ==0` does not indicate 'null bytes'. It indicates end of stream. The socket should be closed.

Comment: @EJP `handle_null_bytes()` just mean `n==0`, I don't know why you think that it related to some other reason